# MAPQuest Disabling DoubleClick Behaviour

Tags: javascript, zooming, mapquest

I am working with existing MapQuest maps and I have to implement the functionality that I have to restrict user to double click and zoom the map, from the API documentation I can see options only to disable but there is no code snippet.

```
window.map = new MQA.TileMap(document.getElementById('map'), 2, null, 'map');
```

this was previous implementation,
I have edited and added option below and its not working,

```
window.map = new MQA.TileMap(document.getElementById('map'), 2, null, 'map', {zoomOnDoubleClick: false});
```

below lines I have added, `,`{zoomOnDoubleClick: false}``

here is the API guide link [API Guide LINK](https://developer.mapquest.com/docs/api-reference/javascript-api/classes/MQA.TileMap.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an options object, set the values you want, then pass that in

```
var options = {
  elt: document.getElementById('map'),       // ID of map element on page
  zoom: 10,                                  // initial zoom level of the map
  latLng: { lat: 39.7439, lng: -105.0200 },  // center of map in latitude/longitude
  mtype: 'map',                              // map type (map, sat, hyb); defaults to map
  bestFitMargin: 0,                          // margin offset from map viewport when applying a bestfit on shapes
  zoomOnDoubleClick: false                    // disable map from zooming in when double-clicking
};

// construct an instance of MQA.TileMap with the options object
window.map = new MQA.TileMap(options);
```

Comment: Thanks.. @Anthony.. The MapQuest support did provide that solution to me two days ago.